# Print a List of objects from another class in c#

Tags: c#

I have created a booklist in a class called "Librarian" and if I
try to print the booklist from the same class it works just fine.
But when I try to do the same thing from another class it will not work
at all.
Can any one see what mistake I have made perhaps help me with an solution?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Librarian obj = new Librarian();
            obj.AddToBooklist();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class Book
    {
        public string author;
        public String title;
    }
    class Librarian
    {
        public List<Book> booklist = new List<Book>();
        public void AddToBooklist()
        {
            //create a book to add into booklist
            Novel newBook = new Novel();
            newBook.author = "Henri";
            newBook.title = "Papillon";
            booklist.Add(newBook);

            foreach (var item in booklist)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.author + " " + item.title);// Prints fine
            }
            Console.WriteLine(booklist[0].author + " " + booklist[0].title);// prints fine too
            // create an object to get into Novel class
            Novel objNovel = new Novel();
            objNovel.Print();
        }
    }
    class Novel : Book
    {
        public void Print()
        {
            Librarian objLib = new Librarian();// create object to get into Librarian class

            foreach (var item in objLib.booklist)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.author + " " + item.title);// prints nothing
            }
            Console.WriteLine(objLib.booklist[0].author); // causes program to crash
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into generics.

Comment: You don't have the `AddToBooklist` called (in the `Novel`), how do you expect it to print anything, you didn't add anything to the list. Your `Main` does that properly. If you need to populate list on Librarian creation then put it in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your code, the instance of type Novel does not have any books added to the book list.

Change your code to something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Librarian obj = new Librarian();
        obj.AddToBooklist();

        //this needs to be moved here, instead to be in the add to book list method.
        Novel objNovel = new Novel();
        objNovel.Print();

        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }
}

class Book
{
    public string author;
    public String title;
}

class Librarian
{
    public List<Book> booklist = new List<Book>();
    public void AddToBooklist()
    {
        //create a book to add into booklist
        Novel newBook = new Novel();
        newBook.author = "Henri";
        newBook.title = "Papillon";
        booklist.Add(newBook);

        foreach (var item in booklist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.author + " " + item.title);// Prints fine
        }
        Console.WriteLine(booklist[0].author + " " + booklist[0].title);// prints fine too
    }                                                             // create an object to get into Novel class 
}

class Novel : Book
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Librarian objLib = new Librarian();// create object to get into Librarian class

        objLib.AddToBooklist();//invoke the method that will add the book to the list

        foreach (var item in objLib.booklist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.author + " " + item.title);// prints nothing
        }
        Console.WriteLine(objLib.booklist[0].author); // causes program to crash
    }
}
```

Update #1.

Answering the first question, lead to the endless looping problem. I took your code and changed it a bit. The initial fix I wrote still remains. Additional I moved the piece of code:

```
  Novel objNovel = new Novel();
  objNovel.Print();
```

To the main method, instead its original position (please see question).

Hope this helps, 
cheers and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your help but I don't think I fully understand. Do you mean that the book that was added to the booklist in Librarian class doesn't exist in the booklist when I try to print it in the Novel class ? Did something happend when I created an object to get access to the Novel class. If I insert objLib.AddToBooklist(); as suggested the program will gi into an endless loop. I stll have a problem

Comment: Updated the answer. I needed to change the code a bit more. If this helps you and you like the answer, please mark the answer as accepted. 

Thank you, cheers and happy coding.